# Iteration over two lists using index

Tags: python, loops, indexing

I am trying to create a list of time and date at specific intervals. The times and dates are present in a time series csv and I want to write a code that extracts data from specific time intervals. I made two lists for day and hour and I am creating a new variable that that stores the date and time of interest. I have trying the following code but I get error:

```
day = ['01', '02', '03', '04', "05", '06', '07', '08', '09', '10', '11', '12','13','14','15','16','17','18'
      '19','20','21','22','23','24','25','26','27','28','29','30','31']
hour = ['0', '3', '6', '9', '12', '15','18','21']
year, month, day, hour = year, month, day, hour # 2016-01-01 @01:00 am
day_time = []
for i in day.index:
    for j in hour.index:
        day_time = int("".join(day[i], hour[j], "00",))
print(day_time)
```

---

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-72-15de17abf279> in <module>
      6 year, month, day, hour = year, month, day, hour # 2016-01-01 @01:00 am
      7 day_time = []
----> 8 for i in day.index:
      9     for j in hour.index:
     10         day_time = int("".join(day[i], hour[j], "00",))

TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not iterable
```

can someone suggest a solution?

Comment: `index` is not what you think it is. It is a function to find the position of a value in a list. Instead use `for i in range(len(day))` and do the same for `hour`

Comment: Also it should be `day_time.append(...)` not `day_time = ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`index` is a function, not an attribute for `list` instance. please refer to [Data structures](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html)

also, the `join` function of a `str` data type takes iterables, refer to [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join)

Also, as @Lecdi pointed, you should use `append` to add to a list instead of redefinition of the variable using `=`; please refer to [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#lists)

to be able to do what you want to do:

```
day = ['01', '02', '03', '04', "05", '06', '07', '08', '09', '10', '11', '12','13','14','15','16','17','18'
      '19','20','21','22','23','24','25','26','27','28','29','30','31']
hour = ['0', '3', '6', '9', '12', '15','18','21']
year, month, day, hour = year, month, day, hour # 2016-01-01 @01:00 am
day_time = []
for day_i in day:
    for hour_i in hour:
        day_time.append(int("".join([day_i, hour_i, "00"])))
print(day_time)
```

Comment: Thanks. It works as well :)

Answer (score 0):

I think `enumerate()` would work better for you

```
for indexDay, valueDay in enumerate(day):
    for indexHour, valueHour in enumerate(hour):
        day_time.append(int("".join([valueDay, valueHour, "00"])))
```

Comment: Firstly, the result this code produces could be better obtained using `zip()` and secondly it produces the wrong result - they want to iterate over two lists and use different indexes for each, not the same index for both lists

Comment: What do you mean by string formatting capability?? In any case, the semantics would be different so it depends on what the OP wants